# Can we execute puppeteer in Cpanel with NodeJS without root privilege or WHM access?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cpanel

I was able to run puppeteer in localhost/VPS but I never install puppeteer in Cpanel because I don't have any Cpanel with NodeJS feature. So before I'm going to buy that Cpanel, I decided to ask here.

Can we execute puppeteer in Cpanel with NodeJS without root privilege or WHM access?